# firefox plugin like update scanner?

Tags: firefox, plugins, firefox-extensions

update scanner is based around great idea - however it just does not work as fast as it should. I have opened 6 links and after hour of waiting FF took 1,6GB of memory. is there any other plugin like that with better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [AlertBox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/alertbox/), the extension has got a help [forum](http://pulsvu.com/forum/7) where examples for use cases, general topics related to AlertBox, suggestions, bugs are being discussed.

I've been using AlertBox for several weeks, during that time I could never observe such a huge memory consumption as you mentioned for Update Scanner.
I also tried other extensions including Site Delta and Update Scanner, but both of them, in my opinion, have several disadvantages compared to AlertBox.
Site Delta's icon is almost hidden, Update Scanner only updates five minutes minimum.